# AutoHotKey: How to maximize the Netflix metro app

Tags: microsoft-metro, autohotkey, netflix

Using AutoHotKey, I'm trying to maximize the Netflix metro when it is already running and minimized.  I haven't had any luck so far.

Here is the script I've tried:

```
^!z::
WinActivate Netflix
WinShow Netflix
WinMaximize Netflix
return
```

Here's what AHK Window Spy says about the Netflix metro app:

```
>>>>>>>>>>( Window Title & Class )<<<<<<<<<<<
Netflix
ahk_class Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow

>>>>>>>>>>>>( Mouse Position )<<<<<<<<<<<<<
On Screen:  528, 738  (less often used)
In Active Window:   528, 738

>>>>>>>>>( Now Under Mouse Cursor )<<<<<<<<

Color:  0x8B7272  (Blue=8B Green=72 Red=72)

>>>>>>>>>>( Active Window Position )<<<<<<<<<<
left: 0     top: 0     width: 1360     height: 768

>>>>>>>>>>>( Status Bar Text )<<<<<<<<<<

>>>>>>>>>>>( Visible Window Text )<<<<<<<<<<<

>>>>>>>>>>>( Hidden Window Text )<<<<<<<<<<<

>>>>( TitleMatchMode=slow Visible Text )<<<<

>>>>( TitleMatchMode=slow Hidden Text )<<<<
```

Answer (score 1):

- Try to launch script with admin privileges.
- Always use AutoHotkey and its documentation from
  http://ahkscript.org/ (current uptodate version, new official
  website)! AutoHotkey and its documentation from autohotkey.com is
  outdated and you may have some problems using them!

I am not user of metro applications but here are my thoughts. If `WinActivate`, `WinShow`, `WinMaximize` command are not working and my above suggestions are not helping too as far as I know you are left with only one solution:

1. You have to activate window of minimized Netflix by clicking with
   [Click](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/Click.htm) command on minimized Netflix.
2. Use [ImageSearch](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/ImageSearch.htm) for getting coordinates to use with [Click](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/Click.htm) command or enter coordinates manually.

Comment: I tried running as administrator but it didn't have any noticeable effect.  I also double checked the documentation and everything looks correct.  Thanks for the suggestions none the less.

Answer (score 0):

The best option I've found so far is to re-run explorer.exe to restart the Netflix metro app, even if it's already running minimized.

```
;Start Netflix
^!z::
Run explorer.exe netflix:
return
```

This causes the Netflix app to load in the foreground without creating multiple instances of the app.  However as a side-effect it causes the app to navigate back to the 1st screen.

I haven't found a better way.